# Including bundled webpack file in webpack build

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a webpack bundled widget that I pack into a single file using webpack, and can use as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="my-bundle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   (function() { 
      MyBundle.render();
   }) ();
</script>
```

This works fine, but I want to use this widget in my main Rails app. So I've copied the `my-bundle.js` file into my main project directory and required it.

When I run webpack on my main app, I can see that the code in `my-bundle` is being included in the resulting js file, but I cannot access the code. i.e. calling `MyBundle` gives a not defined error.

How can I access it?

EDIT - it looks like I can just use `script-loader` to run the `my-bundle.js` file once (which defines a `MyBundle` function). This doesn't feel like the best way to do it though

Comment: Are you requiring the bundled file from your main project or the source file?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. I am putting the file inside my repo with all the other js files that get bundled by webpack.